# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle

I am new in react native and android development.
Currently I want to build an APK but I faced this error.

**FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
>   Could not resolve project :react-native-cookies.
>        Required by:
>            project :app
>   Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-cookies: None of the consumable configurations have attributes.**

In build.gradle file

```
    release {

      signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       matchingFallbacks = ['release', 'debug'] 
    }
  }


dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-cookies')
    implementation project(':react-native-clear-app-cache')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-image-picker')
    implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation project(':react-native-reanimated')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation project(':react-native-orientation')

}
```

In app/build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3" //28.0.3
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28 //28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"


    }

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

I dont know how to solve as I tried many times to modified buildToolsVersion, buildTypes and so on. Any idea to solve this issue? Please help.

Comment: I solved it by,
  ./gradlew clean build --refresh-dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Please Add This into your **Build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    def multidex_version = "2.0.1"
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version"
}
```

and Also Add This

```
  defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
                }
```

This will solve your issue

Comment: It would be beneficial to state which build.gradle, and be more specific as to the 'where' to put things in the file/section/whatever

Answer (score 1):

Check this out

```
dependencies {       
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
}
```

in your build:gradle (module)

Answer (score -1):

In `android/app/build.gradle`
replace:

```
...
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.1' // old
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0-alpha03' // new
...
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.1' // old
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0-alpha03' // new
...
```

Comment: The original poster didn't include these details, so you are making an assumption here and not necessarily answering his question. furthermore, it seems odd, the question is about a resolution problem with the `react-native-cookies` package, if you know for sure, that's the right solution, you should at least explain (even if vaguely), why is this the right fix